# How to fix first Monday of month coinciding with first day of month issue?

Tags: sql-server

[Here is a Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d49874/1)

**Problem:**

I have the following table with currency holidays for USD & AUD currencies. 
I am trying to select the 2022 occurrence using this date table. 
 *[there may be better alternatives but this is what I have to work with]* 
 The output using my query is correct apart from the case where I am looking to return the first Monday of the month and this also falls on the first day of the month. (e.g. 1st August 2022 - Bank Holiday NSW)

| hol_ccy | holiday | start_dt | expiry_dt | date_type | hol_day_no | hol_day | hol_month | observe_d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USD | Columbus Day | 12/30/1900 | 12/31/9999 | Ordinal Day Month | 2 | 2 | 10 | Actual Observed |
| USD | Labor Day | 12/30/1900 | 12/31/9999 | Ordinal Day Month | 1 | 2 | 9 | Actual Observed |
| USD | Martin Luther King J | 12/30/1900 | 12/31/9999 | Ordinal Day Month | 3 | 2 | 1 | Ignored |
| USD | Memorial Day | 1/1/2017 | 12/31/2017 | Ordinal Day Month | 5 | 2 | 5 | Actual Observed |
| USD | Memorial Day | 1/1/2018 | 12/31/2020 | Ordinal Day Month | 4 | 2 | 5 | Actual Observed |
| USD | Memorial Day | 1/1/2027 | 12/30/2028 | Ordinal Day Month | 5 | 2 | 5 | Actual Observed |
| USD | Memorial Day | 1/1/2021 | 12/30/2023 | Ordinal Day Month | 5 | 2 | 5 | Actual Observed |
| USD | Memorial Day | 1/1/2029 | 12/31/2031 | Ordinal Day Month | 4 | 2 | 5 | Actual Observed |
| USD | Memorial Day | 1/1/2024 | 12/31/2026 | Ordinal Day Month | 4 | 2 | 5 | Actual Observed |
| USD | Presidents Day | 12/30/1900 | 12/31/9999 | Ordinal Day Month | 3 | 2 | 2 | Actual Observed |
| USD | Thanksgiving Day | 12/30/1900 | 12/31/9999 | Ordinal Day Month | 4 | 5 | 11 | Actual Observed |
| AUD | Labour Day NSW | 12/30/1900 | 12/31/9999 | Ordinal Day Month | 1 | 2 | 10 | Actual Observed |
| AUD | Bank Holiday NSW | 12/30/1900 | 12/31/9999 | Ordinal Day Month | 1 | 2 | 8 | Actual Observed |
| AUD | Queens Birthday | 12/30/1900 | 12/31/9999 | Ordinal Day Month | 2 | 2 | 6 | Actual Observed |

**My Query:**

```
SELECT a.hol_ccy AS "CURRENCY",
       a.holiday AS "HOLIDAY NAME",
       ( CASE
           WHEN ( a.expiry_dt = '99991231'
                   OR a.expiry_dt = '47121231' )
                 OR ( a.start_dt <= '20220101'
                      AND a.expiry_dt >= '20221231' ) THEN ( Dateadd (day, (
           Datediff (day, a.hol_day - 2, Dateadd (month, Datediff(month,
                                                         0
         ,
                                                         Cast(
         Concat(a.hol_month, '/01/2022') AS DATE)
         )
         , 0)) / 7 ) * 7 + ( a.hol_day_no * 7 ), a.hol_day - 2) )
           ELSE NULL
         END )   AS "DATE",
       a.date_type AS "DATE TYPE"
FROM   Holidays a
WHERE  date_type IN ( 'Ordinal Day Month' )
       AND a.hol_ccy <> 'NONE'
       AND ( ( a.expiry_dt = '99991231'
                OR a.expiry_dt = '47121231' )
              OR ( a.start_dt <= '20220101'
                   AND a.expiry_dt >= '20221231' ) )
```

**A really ugly functional attempt:**

```
SELECT a.hol_ccy   AS "CURRENCY",
       a.holiday   AS "HOLIDAY NAME",
       ( CASE
           WHEN A.hol_day = 2
                AND a.hol_day_no = 1 THEN ( CASE
                                              WHEN ( a.expiry_dt = '99991231'
                                                      OR a.expiry_dt =
                                                         '47121231' )
                                                    OR ( a.start_dt <=
                                                         '20220101'
                                                         AND a.expiry_dt >=
                                                             '20221231'
                                                       )
                                            THEN (
           Dateadd (day, (
                                              Datediff (day, a.hol_day - 2,
                                              Dateadd (
                                              month, Datediff(month,
                                                     0
                                            ,
                                                     Cast(
                                            Concat(a.hol_month, '/01/2022') AS
                                            DATE)
                                            )
                                            , 0)) / 7 ) * 7 +
                         ( a.hol_day_no * 7 ),
           a.hol_day - 2
           ) )
                                              ELSE NULL
                                            END ) - 7
           ELSE ( CASE
                    WHEN ( a.expiry_dt = '99991231'
                            OR a.expiry_dt = '47121231' )
                          OR ( a.start_dt <= '20220101'
                               AND a.expiry_dt >= '20221231' ) THEN
                    ( Dateadd (day, (
                    Datediff (day, a.hol_day - 2, Dateadd (month,
                                                  Datediff(month,
                                                  0
                  ,
                                                                  Cast(
                  Concat(a.hol_month, '/01/2022') AS DATE)
                  )
                  , 0)) / 7 ) * 7 + ( a.hol_day_no * 7 ), a.hol_day - 2) )
                    ELSE NULL
                  END )
         END )     AS "DATE",
       a.date_type AS "DATE TYPE"
FROM   Holidays a
WHERE  date_type IN ( 'Ordinal Day Month' )
       AND a.hol_ccy <> 'NONE'
       AND ( ( a.expiry_dt = '99991231'
                OR a.expiry_dt = '47121231' )
              OR ( a.start_dt <= '20220101'
                   AND a.expiry_dt >= '20221231' ) )
```

I don't quite understand why the specific case for e.g. 1st August 2022 - Bank Holiday NSW does not work using the first query attempt? Is there a better way of writing the second functional attempt?

Comment: it is much easier if you have a calendar table

Comment: [`DATEFROMPARTS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql) is a thing in SQL Server to help you avoid that brittle code you have trying to convert strings to dates.

Comment: Also your holiday data seems incorrect: In Queensland, AU, the Queen's Birthday holiday is the 1st Monday in October, e.g.: 2021-10-04, 2022-10-03, 2023-10-02.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d49874/23